# Prepend "player-" before numeric URLs with the help of HAProxy 1.5

Tags: redirect, rewrite, haproxy, 301-redirect

I run a web game embedded in Wordpress/Jetty behind HAProxy 1.5 on CentOS 7 Linux.

The website can be accessed both as `http` and `https`.

I have modified Wordpress to display player profile pages at the URLs like:

```
https://slova.de/player-12345
```

where `12345` is a numeric player id in my web game.

This works well, but I would like to simplify the above URLs to

```
https://slova.de/12345
```

and then use [HAProxy](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#http-request) to **prepend the "player-" part to numeric-only paths**.

So I have added to `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` file the line:

```
http-request redirect code 301 prefix /player- if { path_end /5 }
```

This results however in the broken URL for some reason:

> https://slova.de/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/player-/5

Below is my complete `haproxy.cfg` file to provide more context:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

    # for WebSocket connections
    timeout tunnel          1h
    timeout client-fin      1m

frontend public
    bind 144.76.184.151:80
    bind 144.76.184.151:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/slova.de.pem no-sslv3
    http-request deny if { path_beg /xmlrpc.php }

    http-request redirect code 301 prefix /player- if { path_end /5 }

    default_backend jetty

backend jetty
    server domain 127.0.0.1:8080 send-proxy
```

Comment: For what it's worth, doing something like this would be super easy in nginx; if you're just running wordpress and jetty, seems like an overkill to be using a big-guy-kinda tool that literally has High Availability in its name!  (nginx, on the other hand, is quite popular with all kinds of installations, big or small, and is equally good for both front-end and backend tasks.)

Answer (score 1):

This means you are sending a 301 redirect response to every request that has the number `5` in the end of the URL.

So, if your first request is for `http://www.example.com/5`, your configuration would send a HTTP 301 redirect to URL `http://www.example.com/player-5`. The browser then requests this URL, and HAProxy again sends the HTTP 301 redirect, now to `http://www.example.com/player-/player-5` and so on, until some URL length limit is reached.

I assume that you don't want to do a 301 redirect here, but attach the `player-` prefix to the request going to Jetty. To make this happen, you need to use the `http-request set-path` directive.

However, if you want to do a `301 redirect`, then you need to refine your condition so that the redirect is only done when there is no `player-` prefix in the URL.

For example, this could work:

```
http-request redirect code 301 prefix /player- if { path_end /5 and !path_end /player-5 }
```

I haven't used HAProxy myself, so this is only based on the HAProxy documentation and my interpretation on how its ACLs work.

Comment: I have tried `http-request set-path` before and HAProxy 1.5 does not know it yet. And I would like to keep using that version coming as CentOS 7 Linux package. Can I use regex with `path_end` or should I use some other directive please?

Comment: I updated the answer with one possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately `http-request redirect code 301 prefix /player- if { path_end /5 and !path_end /player-5 }` suffers the same problem of too long repeating URL.